# Doing a calculation while querying the database in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, database

I want to obtain the objects of my `Project` model for whose ratio of the values in the two fields `raised_amount` and `total_amount` is less than 0.2. 
I have been trying this 
    `project_list = Project.objects.filter((raised_amount)/(total_amount)<0.2)`

I know this is the wrong way. Please help me do it the right way

Comment: hi @arjun-mehra 1) Have you tried Google?

Comment: yes I did but I didn't get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
from django.db.models import F
Project.objects.annotate(x=F('raised_amount') / F('total_amount')).filter(x__lt=0.2)
```

Comment: I tried this but something isn't working right. I tried finding the issue but failed. I am just a starter with Django. Please help! My `Project` model has these fields: `total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    
raised_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)`

I have an object for which the ratio 'raised_amount/total_amount` is 0.65, but it's still showing in the filter for `0.2`... What might be the problem?